# How much air ventilation required for oil burner in a closet?

Tags: boiler, renovation

We are redoing our basement and closeting off the boiler and hot water heater. With our layout, it makes most sense to vent it out of the chimney. However, I want to make sure we are getting enough air draw. Does anyone know if slated doors are enough? Is there a better system I'm not thinking of?

Comment: That's a fairly loaded question for a potentially dangerous situation and with very little information. Perhaps update your question with a model number or accurate description of the unit?

Answer (score 1):

According to NFPA 31, you'll need two openings. One near the top, and one near the bottom. Each of which must be 1 in.² per 1000 Btu/h of the input rating of all the appliances in the confined space.

> ## NFPA 31 Standard for Installation of Oil Burning Equipment.
>
> ### Chapter 5 Air for Combustion and Ventilation.
>
> **5.4 Appliances Located in Confined Spaces.**
>
> **5.4.1 All Air Taken from Inside the Building.**
>
> **5.4.1.1** The confined space shall be provided with two permanent openings as shown in figure 5.4.1.1, one near the top of the space and one near the bottom.
>
> **5.4.1.2** Each opening shall have a free area of not less than 1 in.² per 1000 Btu/h (140 in.² per gal/h) (22 cm²/kw), based on the total input rating of all appliances in the space.
>
> [image: Figure 5.4.1.1]